# Include through HTTP

Tags: php, include, require

I have a file on another server which I can trust since it's my own code that in it there is an array with some settings.

When I include it using the include_once and print_r the variable in it, I am getting an undefined variable.

I also tried to return the variable from the file I am including and assign it to a variable in the script like this:

```
$var = include($url);
```

where $url has:

```
$array = array(1,2,3); return $array;
```

when I `print_r($var)` I only get 1.

Comment: Turn on `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and see if that explains it.

Comment: @mario - should it show something special? nothing came up. and yes I do have allow_url_include in my php.ini

Comment: Why don't set the array into the file to include? and then call it? You must have a reason to do it the way you are trying.

Comment: That's what I was asking about. -- Bodyloss is right. Include() only sees the output of the script. Return values are not transferred cross-server. Your description of what $url contains was invalid.

Answer (score 2):

It's because the other server will parse the file and return the RESULT, not the actual code. you need to get the actual contents of the file, which will only be possible if you disable php on the other server or ftp to it.
I would recommend copying the file over to the server you're working on, safer an easier

The file you are trying to get will come back the same as if you went there in your web browser because the remote web server will parse the contents of the file though the php engine.

Comment: Or by using another extension which is not interpreted (such as .txt) or outputting the code to be executed yourself.

Comment: no, as @fishfisk stated, you either need to change the file type or output the code that you want to execute by doing include(*)

Comment: the script on the other server will be outputting text, not a php array. so no it'll be much safer to just copy the file across.

Answer (score 1):

remote host:

```
echo serialize($array);
```

local host:

```
$array = unserialize(file_get_contents($url));
```

Comment: i actually can't do that since it's being used in other places - guess i have to copy the functionality of creating the file on the current server :/

Comment: @hex4: Any making a second wrapper script would be too much effort?